# Is there a work around to turning flex items to containers?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I notice when adding the flex attribute to a flex item, that flex item over flows its container. Is there a way to contain that flex item? I guess it would be considered a nested flex-container?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flex-box is a complex parent-child positioning relation with multiple attributes on both parent and children. Please note that the `flex` attribute on an item is a shorthand property for `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis`, in that order.

While it might seem like it affects overflowing in some cases, it actually does not. That is strictly controlled by the `overflow` property. You could easily test this by setting a thin border on parents and/or children (`border: 1px solid red;`) while playing with `flex` and `overflow`.

You will notice [`flex`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/) does not change or control [`overflow`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html). It might change the shape and position, which might result in a child overflowing its parent or other siblings, but it doesn't change or control the `overflow` property.

`overflow` defaults to `visible` on all html elements.

Comment: yes the child overflows its parent when the screen size changes but the overflow property does help with my issue thank you